# How to convert decimal tofixed foramt using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

My table has decimal values. My question is how to convert all decimal values  after 2 digit decimal point.

Example:

1)My table column value is 11.9 and 6.0. how convert to this format 11.90 and 06.00

2)1045.7 to 1045.70

[image]

i am using django to display the value .my html table code using this format than how to convert tofixed

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered " id="child_table">
     <thead class="btn-primary" >
     <tr>

                <th >Year</th>
                <th >Estimated Mid-Year-Population</th>
                <th colspan="3" >Infanticide</th>
                <th colspan="3" >Murder</th>
                <th colspan="3" >Rape</th>
                <th colspan="3" >Kidnapping & Abduction</th>
                <th colspan="3" >Abetment Of Suicide</th>
                <th colspan="3" >Child Marriage Restraint Act</th>
                <th colspan="3" >Other Crimes</th>

     </tr>

    </thead>
```

```
  <td></td>
  <th></th>
  <th>(I)ncidance</th>
     <th>(R)ate</th>
     <th>%</th>
     <th>I</th>
     <th>R</th>
     <th>%</th>
     <th>I</th>
     <th>R</th>
    <th>%</th>
     <th>I</th>
     <th>R</th>
     <th>%</th>
    <th>I</th>
     <th>R</th>
     <th>%</th>
     <th>I</th>
     <th>R</th>
     <th>%</th>
     <th>I</th>
     <th>R</th>
    <th>%</th>

</tr>
```

```
        <tbody id="crimec">
         {% for query_all in crime_filter %}
             <tr id="crime_child">

                 <td>{{ query_all.year}}</td>
                <td>{{ query_all.mid_year_population }}</td>

                <td>{{ query_all.infanticide_incidence }}</td>


                  {% if query_all.infanticide_rate > 0 %}
                 <td>{{ query_all.infanticide_rate }}</td>
                 {% else %}
                 <td> </td>
                 {% endif %}
                <td>{{ query_all.infanticide_percentage }}</td>
                <td>{{ query_all.murder_incidence }}</td>
                  <td>{{ query_all.murder_rate }}</td>
                  <td>{{ query_all.murder_percentage }}</td>
                <td>{{ query_all.rape_incidence }}</td>
                  <td>{{ query_all.rape_rate }}</td>
                  <td>{{ query_all.rape_percentage }}</td>
                <td>{{ query_all.kidnapping_abduction_i }}</td>
             <td>{{ query_all.kidnapping_abduction_r }}</td>
             <td>{{ query_all.kidnapping_abduction_p }}</td>
             <td>{{ query_all.abetment_suicide_i }}</td>
              {% if query_all.abetment_suicide_r > 0 %}
             <td>{{ query_all.abetment_suicide_r }}</td>
             {% else %}
                 <td> </td>
             {% endif %}
             <td>{{ query_all.abetment_suicide_p }}</td>
             <td>{{ query_all.child_marriage_act_i }}</td>

              {% if query_all.child_marriage_act_r > 0%}
             <td>{{ query_all.child_marriage_act_r }}</td>
             {% else %}
                 <td> </td>
             {% endif %}
             <td>{{ query_all.child_marriage_act_p }}</td>
             <td>{{ query_all.total_i }}</td>
             <td>{{ query_all.total_r }}</td>
             <td>{{ query_all.total_p }}</td>

            </tr>

         {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this with Javascript, rather than when outputting in the template with the `floatformat` filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CODE:

```
   var val=6;
var precision=2;
val = val.toFixed(precision);
if( val < 10.00 )
    val = "0"+val
alert(val)
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NM296/1)

Comment: how to apply tofixed in my html table

Comment: you can have the same `class` for all `<td>` tags you wish to change.

Comment: @KrishnaM i am adding all the <td> to same class .then i cant understad how apply tofixed

Comment: `var val = $(.class_name).text(); val = parseFloat(val); ` Then apply the above function

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = 11.9;

if(!isInt(value)){

      var changeValue = value.toFixed(2);
}

console.log(changeValue); // returns 11.90

// check int or float;
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
   }
```

Comment: how to apply to this all decimal table values

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Number.toFixed() method.

```
  var num = 5.5;
  console.log(num.toFixed(2)) // this will return 5.50
```

Comment: how to apply tofixed in my html table

Comment: I created a simple function for looping through all the cells and doing the conversion. I also added another function for doing the conversion for one specific column. You need to add a table id. Check the http://jsfiddle.net/STNwS/

Answer (score 1):

Use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) in combination with [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
parseFloat(6).toFixed(2);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/25hJC/

Comment: how to apply tofixed in my html table